# Correlation matrix between different files

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have 82 .csv files, each of them a zoo object, with the following format:
`"Index",   "code",   "pp"

1951-01-01, 2030, 22.9

1951-01-02, 2030,  0.5

1951-01-03, 2030,  0.0`

I want to do a correlation matrix between the pp of all of my files. I found out how to do it "manually" between two files:
`zz<-merge(x,y, all = FALSE)

z<-cbind(zz[,2], zz[,4])

cor(z,use= "complete.obs")`

but I can't come up with a loop to do it for all the files... a few things to consider: each file starts and ends at different dates and I would like the matrix to show the codes so I can identify who is who.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have the bones of a perfectly good solution here, actually. If you start with `list.files()` to generate a list of your csv files:

```
fileList <- list.files(path="path/to/csv/files")
```

then read in all the files using `lapply()`:

```
datList <- lapply(fileList,read.csv)
```

then merge the first two files (assuming the code is the same for each file):

```
dat <- merge(datList[[1]][,-2],datList[[2]][,-2],by="Index",
        suffixes=c(datList[[1]]$code[1],datList[[2]]$code[1]))
```

The `suffixes` argument will help you name the columns by code, for future reference. Then loop over the rest of datList using a simple for loop, merging each one with dat:

```
for (i in 3:length(datList)){
    dat <- merge(dat,datList[[i]][,-2],by="Index",suffixes=datList[[i]]$code[1])
}
```

and then you should be able to run `cor` on `dat` minus the first column. You might have to tweak this code a bit, but this general idea ought to work.

Comment: thanks for your code, but it's not working and I can't figure out why. The data.frame dat looks like this:   `Index pp3195 pp2030 pp2059 ppNA pp2113 ppNA pp2234.1 ppNA pp2290 ppNA pp2422 ppNA 
18592 2010-12-26    0.0     NA     NA    0      0  0.0      0.0   NA     `  
So it's not reading some of the suffixes and they don't seem to be in order either, so I can't figure out who is who. Any idea why?

Comment: Hard to say w/out a direct look at your full data. The ppNA's suggest that you have some files with NAs in the code column, and the pp2234.1 suggests that either you have a non-integer code, or duplicate codes (two files for code 2234). My code will put the columns in the order they appear in list.files; you could reorder them by coercing the column names to character and using `order()`.

Comment: thanks I really had some NAs in the code that were causing problems